# Single login form for multiple user

Tags: php, design-patterns, web, authentication

I'm working on a project which has many user type such as `Contributor`, `Operator`, `CS`, `Admin` with different roles and tasks. For now I separate login form just 2, one for Admin only and one another for the rest type of user. The problem for the time being I could not have same `credentials` for different type of user, for example if I have username "employee1" and password "emp1secreet" for type of user `Contributor` then I can't have same those username and password for `Operator` because single login form handles with single business model, I can't guarantee if person who log in is `Operator` or `Contributor`, but anything else it's doesn't matter. My question is **"is common to have single login form for multiple user?"** or I need separate them into each different login form/page?
thanks for your help

Comment: you can have one form for every-one. just check through query what type of user is trying to login to the system and based on that do stuff accordingly.Also make your fields unique to remove duplicate entries at the time of registration.

Comment: So I need add preferences to allow user select their role when login? like log as "Contributor" or "Operator", or "CS"? but it's look weird if that website for public, I never know public web like that..

Comment: No man at the time just take there username and password and through the query check what type of user they are

Comment: Yes that's the way what I do with my business model for login, I check one by one from each table (Operator, Contributor, CS), but if there are 2 person which have the same username and password and they are have different user type then the first person who selected by query would log in, isn't?

Comment: Create one table `user` which contain `user_type` and one table`user_types` where you store user-types like `1.contributer,2.operator` and at the time of registration add id to   `user_type` column in the `user` table. Also make `username` unique so that every user have unique name

Comment: @Anant yes sometime I use that model, so the table Contributor, Operator, CS have relation one-to-one with table users? hmm then I prevent user register with same combination username and password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal login forms give the user the ability to enter a username and password, and then the application goes to a database of users to obtain what permissions they have. So different users cannot have the same user-id, but may have different levels of permissions/access into a site/application.

You may well wish to have a database table with columns:

```
UserID[string], isContributor[bool], isOperator[bool], isAdmin[bool], isCS[bool]
```

or you could do it with bit-flags in a single permissions column that has room for expansion to make it easier to add more role-types later.

Comment: I think if role management better with table junction between users and table roles or the users table relate with user type instead your table design, but my question is how dealing with the possibility when user in different type have same username and password if I only have 1 login form or I need to separate them into different login form.

Comment: There are many ways of doing this, I suspect it's down to the the preferences and usability of what you want to do. I would never allow two users of a system to have the same user id (let alone password), but it may well be that a single user of multiple systems will re-use the same user-id/password combination for all of their logins - in which case a separate login page for each system would be the way to go (or start looking in to single-sign-on methods). Or, when a user logs in, show them a dialog to select which role they wish to utilise if that's more appropriate (and they've >1 role)

Comment: Yes, that the statement reassure me select and consider the model. but how about the table scheme itself, do I add username and password field in each user type table of I create one table called credentials and referenced to all user type table with one-to-one relationship?

Comment: Storing usernames and passwords in any table will need thought with respect to determining adequate security for your product. Personally, I'd store them once only (suitably encrypted/protected) so that you don't have an admin nightmare when someone wants to change their password.